# Docker Volume Containers for database, logs and metrics

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-network

I have an application that uses an embedded DB and also generates logs and raw metrics to the following directory structure:

```
/opt/myapp/data/
  database/
  logs/
  raw_metrics/
```

I am in the process of learning Docker and am trying to "Dockerize" this app and am trying to find a mounting/volume solution that accomplishes the following goals for me:

- The embedded database is stored in the same mounted volume regardless of how many container instances of `myapp` that I have running. In other words, all container instances write their data to the shared `database/` volume; and
- I'd also prefer the same for my logs and raw metrics (that is: all container instances write logs/metrics to the same shared volume), except here I need to be able to distinguish log and metrics data for each container. In other words, I need to know that container X generated a particular log message, or that container Y responded to a request in 7 seconds, etc.

I'm wondering what the standard procedure is here in Docker-land. After reading the official Docker docs as well as [this article on Docker Volumes](https://rominirani.com/docker-tutorial-series-part-7-data-volumes-93073a1b5b72) my *tentative* approach is to:

1. Create a Data Volume Container and mount it to, say, `/opt/myapp` on the host machine
2. I can then configure my embedded database to read DB contents from/write them to `/opt/myapp/database`, and I *believe* (if I understand what I've read correctly), all container instances will be sharing the same DB
3. Somehow inject the container ID or some other unique identifier into each container instance, and refactor my logging and metrics code to include that injected ID when generating logs or raw metrics, so that I might have, say, an `/opt/myapp/logs/containerX.log` file, an `/opt/myapp/logs/containerY.log` file, etc. **But I'm very interested in what the standard practice is here for log aggregation amongst Docker containers!**

Also, and arguably much more importantly, is the fact that I'm not sure that this solution would work in a multi-host scenario where I have a Swarm/cluster running dozens of `myapp` containers on multiple hosts. Would my Data Volume Container magically synchronize the `/opt/myapp` volume across all of the hosts? If not, what's the solution for mounting shared volumes for containers, regardless of whatever host they're running on? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple good questions. Following are some of my answers.

1. The default logging driver used by Docker is json-file. This will capture stdout and stderr in json format. There are other logging drivers(like syslog, fluentd, LogEntries etc) that can send to central log server. Using central logging also avoids the problem of maintaining volumes by ourselves. All Docker logging drivers are captured here(https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#supported-logging-drivers)
2. If you use Swarm mode with services, there is a concept of service logging where service logs contains logs associated with all containers associated with the service. (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_logs/)
3. Docker log contains container id by default which is added by logging driver. We can customize it using log options(https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/log_tags/)
4. For sharing data across containers like database, if the containers are in same host, we can use host based volumes. This will not work across nodes as there is no autosync. For sharing container data across nodes, we can either use shared filesystem(like nfs, ceph, gluster) or Docker volume plugins(ebs, gce)

Comment: Thanks @Sreeni (+1) - regarding your first bulletpoint above about logging drivers: I think what I might do is use the `syslog` driver and configure `syslog` on the host. But I **believe** (please correct me if I'm wrong!), that would require me to change my app to log to STDOUT or STDERR, right? How do you configure `syslog` for Docker containers whose internals apps **must** log to a file? For instance if I wanted a Dockerized FTP server [such as this one](https://github.com/fauria/docker-vsftpd/blob/master/vsftpd.conf), I have no say-so as to how that FTP server logs.

Comment: For example, in that particular Docker image, the logging is [configured here](https://github.com/fauria/docker-vsftpd/blob/master/vsftpd.conf#L44), via setting a `xferlog_file` to point to a log file. So how might I use Docker drivers to collect logs from these FTP server containers? Just curious! Thanks again!

Comment: You can make a symbolic link as this: `/path/to/ftp.log -> /dev/stdout` and your ftp will think that is writing to a file. Or directly tell him to write to `/dev/stdout` "file"

Comment: Agree with @Robert. If you look here(https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/view_container_logs/), thats the suggested official approach as well. Infact, containers like nginx and httpd already achieve this by incorporating the links or custom location in Dockerfile as mentioned in link.